# Get only decimal django-money

Tags: django, django-templates

I've instaled django-money module to a project. When try to render in a template, the money file is rendered:

```
 $100.00
```

Is there any method to only render the decimal value without the symbol? Such as:

```
100.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The money field has an `amount` attribute which is an instance of `decimal.Decimal`.  Update your template to refer to the `amount` attribute of your model field:

```
<span>{{ obj.field.amount }}</span>
```